# Merge Replication automatically create rowguid for both Source and Target table

Tags: sql-server

As I was trying to create a publication and subscription on Windows Server 2016 using Merge replication, I found out that on both of my source/target table, there was a new column called `newguid`.

The value of this field is same on both source/target table.

I'm really not sure if that might cause any problem to my current DB or the way I have to query?

From backup/restore point of view, using merge replication is best practice?

Answer (score 0):

This is by design.

According to [Merge Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/merge/merge-replication):

> To track changes, merge replication (and transactional replication
>   with queued updating subscriptions) must be able to uniquely identify
>   every row in every published table. To accomplish this merge
>   replication adds the column rowguid to every table, unless the table
>   already has a column of data type uniqueidentifier with the ROWGUIDCOL
>   property set (in which case this column is used).

To answer your questions:

> I'm really not sure if that might cause any problem to my current DB
>   or the way I have to query?

It depends on what your queries look like and how your application uses the results.  Queries in the form of **`SELECT *`** may be problematic if the application is not expecting the extra rowguid column. You will need to test this.

> From backup/restore point of view, using merge replication is best
>   practice?

I've never had any issues backing up or restoring Merge replicated database that have a rowguid column.